# Windows 11 smartscreen operation

Tags: microsoft-smartscreen

I understand that smartscreen checks the authenticity of executables downloaded from the internet, but I was wondering whether it also prevents unrecognized application to be launched from USB drives, copied on the local drive from external supports, or in any case in which the system has no record the download has occurred (private browsing..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the Microsoft documentation about this: [Microsoft Defender SmartScreen - Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/virus-and-threat-protection/microsoft-defender-smartscreen/).

Short answer: No, SmartScreen is for web browsing monitoring. You're looking for the Anti-Virus features of MS Defender.